# Use of お in the beginning of these question phrases

Tags: politeness, formality, prefixes

Studying Japanese in a book, I saw this dialogue:

```
A:  お名前は？
B:  ペドロです
A:  お国は？
B:  スペインです
```

From what I know, the `お` works as an honorific of respect, then, it is used only in formal phrases. But these phrases do not seem to be formal.

What is the function of `お`? Is `お名前は？` equivalent to `名前は？` ?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23133/9831 -- `the お prefix makes the word 'honorific', which in practice means that the word translates to 'your name'.`

Comment: `these phrases do not seem to be formal.` -- "Formality" and "Politeness" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use o お in begin of these questions phrases
>
> > A:  お名前は？
> > B:  ペドロです
> > A:  お国は？
> > B:  スペインです
>
> From what I know, the お work as a honorific of respect, then, it is used only in formal phrase. But, this phrases do not seem to be formal.

These お are meant to be put on the nouns, 名前 and 国, and is nothing to do whether it's interrogative.

This kind of お (and ご basically for *kango*, or sometimes it's to do with customary, likely for the easiness of pronunciation) is for the purpose of politeness. They makes the *standard language to talk to people*, equivalent to です・ます style. They are called 丁寧語{ていねいご}.

> 敬語の一。話し手が聞き手に対し敬意を表して、丁寧にいう言い方。
> （[ていねいご【丁寧語】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/150311/meaning/m1u/%E4%B8%81%E5%AF%A7%E8%AA%9E/)| デジタル大辞泉）

We also put お to nouns even when there's no need for paying any respect, and these cases are called 美化語{びかご}. All these, now-a-days, are after all about how you want to present yourself; you can create good impression of yourself if you choose to use these words.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the specific context from the book but when meeting somebody for the first time, one typically would use formal language.

Comment: This book have only loose sentences, with 2~4 phrases.

Comment: Sorry, but this dialogue don't have a context. I have only this 4 phrases. The name of the book I'm reading is "Shadowing: Let's Speak Japanese!". You could seen a example of how the book: http://japanesetease.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/shadowing-lets-speak-japanese-7.jpg

Comment: @Macabeus "Formal" and "simple" are different things. Casual sentences can be extremely complicated, and formal sentences can be made of a few words.